# Coded UI Testing of Silverlight in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a Coded UI test for our system which runs on Sharepoint 2010. Part of the test sequence is creating a site; Sharepoint's UI for creating sites runs on Silverlight. Therefore, I need to create a Coded UI test for a Silverlight component which is part of out-of-the-box Sharepoint rather then part of our application. When I try to record a test, I get the following message:

No Silverlight controls where detected. Verify that the application under test is built using Silverlight assemblies with a version of 4.0 or greater and that a reference to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll assembly has been added to the project. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204562

I have two questions:

1) How can I find out the Silverlight version which Sharepoint components are built against? If they are built against Silverlight version 3.5 or earlier - I suppose the problem is unresolvable?

2) Assuming the previous question is answered - how can I make Sharepoint's Silverlight components reference the SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll library? That seems problematic at best to me...

Silverlight version installed on the test machine is 4; Visual Studio Feature Pack 2 is installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make SharePoint's Silverlight components reference the automation helper library unless you have the source code and can recompile them. So the answer to your first question doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify Sharepoint XAPs to simply add Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll in there. You don't really need the code itself to reference it, it just has to part of the package. The XAP file is just a zip file so you should be able to modify this.

You will have to find where Sharepoint is getting the XAPs from and change the source (obviously you don't want to do this in prod boxes and there's even a license restriction for the Automation dll that prevents you from do it). You could also write a Fiddler AutoResponder to modify the XAP file and add the dll before it gets to the browser. For an example of this have a look at this AutoResponder:
https://bitbucket.org/mamadero/hackingsilverlightdemo/src/2fecb7b59dec/FiddlerAutoResponder